# $ variables of CSS not working in Git while using Gulp Watch

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, git, gulp

I have been using Git with Node.JS. Using the gulp.src & gulp.dest methods to organize the CSS files. It's all working fine. The issue comes when I create a CSS file for variables of colors like:

1. $mainBlue: #169aff;
2. $mainBlack: #333333;

I am also importing the variables CSS file into main CSS files like others. But when I use the "gulp watch" and after that, I save the CSS file, I am getting the below error.

This issue doesn't come up when I use the variable ($mainBlue: #169aff;) in the same file along with assigning to an element like "a{color:$mainBlue;) if I use the assigned variable in another file this issue comes up.

> events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ CssSyntaxError: postcss-simple-vars: C:\path\app\assets\styles\modules_btn.css:9:9: Undefined variable
>   $mainBlue
>       at Input.error (C:\path\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:119:22)
>       at Declaration.error (C:\path\node_modules\postcss\lib\node.js:116:38)
>       at Object.opts.unknown (C:\path\node_modules\postcss-simple-vars\index.js:97:24)
>       at variable (C:\path\node_modules\postcss-simple-vars\index.js:24:24)
>       at C:\path\node_modules\postcss-simple-vars\index.js:35:22
>       at String.replace ()
>       at simpleSyntax (C:\path\node_modules\postcss-simple-vars\index.js:34:16)
>       at bothSyntaxes (C:\path\node_modules\postcss-simple-vars\index.js:46:11)
>       at C:*path*\node_modules\postcss-simple-vars\index.js:63:16
>       at repeat (C:\path\node_modules\postcss-simple-vars\index.js:56:20)

Comment: Those variable declarations are at the top of a scss file that is imported before the variables are used in another .scss file?

Comment: Thanks for replying, look I made these two above variables and put it in file "variables.css", and I imported the variables.css into main styles.css file.

When I define the variable to a color like a{color:$mainBlue;} outside the variables.css file, it shows this error.

And If I define the above two variables inside the file in which I am using a{color:$mainBlue;}, it works.